# Vertical Header where each line shows only one letter using css

Tags: html, css

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>M<br/>A<br/>T<br/>H<br/> 1<br/>0<br/>1</th>
    <th>H<br/>I<br/>S<br/>T<br/> 1<br/>0<br/>1</th>
    <th>P<br/>H<br/>S<br/>Y<br/> 1<br/>0<br/>1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to have html table header shown like above. It is possible to set it with css instead of put a tag `</br>` between letters in table head tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) and [`text-orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation) to achieve the result you want:

```css
th {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>MATH 101</th>
    <th>HIST 101</th>
    <th>PHYS 101</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks alot for editing my question and answering it... Many thanks man.